# No instance for (Git.Libgit2.HasLgRepo IO) arising from a use of ‘lookupBlob’

Tags: haskell, libgit2

I am trying to get list of all files in HEAD commit from a git repository using [`gitlib`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib). Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module GitOperations where

import Git
import Git.Libgit2 (lgFactory, LgRepo(..) )
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

repositoryOptions :: RepositoryOptions
repositoryOptions = RepositoryOptions { repoPath = ".git"
                                , repoWorkingDir = Just "."
                                , repoIsBare = False
                                , repoAutoCreate = True}
  
main :: IO ()
main = do
  repo <- openRepository lgFactory repositoryOptions
  runReaderT listHEADFiles repo

listHEADFiles:: ReaderT LgRepo IO ()
listHEADFiles = do 
  ref <- resolveReference $ T.pack "HEAD"
  case ref of
    Nothing -> fail $ "Could not resolve reference named 'HEAD'"
    Just reference -> do
      obj <- lookupObject reference
      case obj of
        CommitObj commit -> do 
          objects <- listAllObjects (Just $ commitOid commit) (commitOid commit)
          lift $ mapM_ (\o -> case o of BlobObjOid boOid -> do blob <- lookupBlob boOid; bc <- blobContents blob; case bc of BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs) objects
        _ -> fail $ "'HEAD' is not a commit object"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Main.hs:33:96: error:
    • Couldn't match kind ‘* -> *’ with ‘*’
      When matching types
        IO :: * -> *
        BlobContents :: (* -> *) -> *
      Expected type: IO (BlobContents m0)
        Actual type: BlobContents IO
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: bc <- blobContents blob
      In the expression:
        do blob <- lookupBlob boOid
           bc <- blobContents blob
           case bc of { BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs }
      In a case alternative:
          BlobObjOid boOid
            -> do blob <- lookupBlob boOid
                  bc <- blobContents blob
                  case bc of { BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs }
   |
33 |           lift $ mapM_ (\o -> case o of BlobObjOid boOid -> do blob <- lookupBlob boOid; bc <- blobContents blob; case bc of BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs) objects
   |                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I do not understand how to go around this error message and how to adapt my code to make typechecker happy. Any tips are appreciated.

Note that git repository should contain at least one commit for the script to work.

UPD: Per @chi's recommendation, I have changed call to `blobContents blob` to be non-monadic, but now that relevant line looks like `lift $ mapM_ (\o -> case o of BlobObjOid boOid -> do blob <- lookupBlob boOid; let bc = blobContents blob in case bc of BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs) objects`, another error comes up and I don't know how to fix it:

```
Main.hs:33:72: error:
    • No instance for (Git.Libgit2.HasLgRepo IO)
        arising from a use of ‘lookupBlob’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: blob <- lookupBlob boOid
      In the expression:
        do blob <- lookupBlob boOid
           let bc = ... in case bc of { BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs }
      In a case alternative:
          BlobObjOid boOid
            -> do blob <- lookupBlob boOid
                  let ... in case bc of { BlobString bs -> ... }
   |
33 |           lift $ mapM_ (\o -> case o of BlobObjOid boOid -> do blob <- lookupBlob boOid; let bc = blobContents blob in case bc of BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs) objects
   |                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I am pretty new to `gitlib` and it is overwhelming for me now that I try to make simple things work with git in haskell. Does anyone have any idea how to make this code compile successfully?

Comment: Your `lift` is misplaced, it should be in front of the `BS.putStrLn`, as `lookupBlob` should run inside `ReaderT LgRepo IO`, not in `IO`.

Comment: This is purely a Haskell language issue. I removed the [tag:git] tag but probably [tag:libgit2] should go away as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I found [the correct documentation page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib-3.1.3/docs/Git-Types.html#t:Blob), `blobContents` looks like a non-monadic function, so you can't use `bc <- blobContents blob`. Use instead `let bc = blobContents blob`.

This is consistent with the error message, which states that the actual type is not wrapped under IO.

```
  Expected type: IO (BlobContents m0)
    Actual type: BlobContents IO
```

Further, you use `lift` too early:

```
lift $ mapM_ (\o -> case o of 
   BlobObjOid boOid -> do
      blob <- lookupBlob boOid
      let bc = blobContents blob
      case bc of BlobString bs -> BS.putStrLn bs
   ) objects
```

Inside the `lift` you are constrained to use `IO` actions, only, and can not use the ones which require `ReaderT LgRepo IO`. To solve this issue, simply move the `lift` inwards:

```
mapM_ (\o -> case o of 
   BlobObjOid boOid -> do
      blob <- lookupBlob boOid
      let bc = blobContents blob
      case bc of BlobString bs -> lift $ BS.putStrLn bs
   ) objects
```

Comment: After I fix it as recommended, I then get following error: `No instance for (Git.Libgit2.HasLgRepo IO)
        arising from a use of ‘lookupBlob’`

Comment: @altern I can't find the docs for that one. Can you share a link to the package? there are too many on Hackage and I can't guess which is the one you are using.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib-3.1.3/docs/Git-Types.html#v:lookupBlob

Comment: @altern I'm not sure, but my guess is this: you use `lift` to turn an IO action into a `ReaderT LgRepo IO` action. Inside the IO action you can use IO (good), but you can no longer use other gitlib stuff since that relies on the `ReaderT LgRepo` part (bad). I would try to remove the `lift`, so that we still work in the outer monad, and add `lift` back only on the IO actions like `BS.putStrLn bs` (which do require the lift).

Comment: that worked! thanks! could you please incorporate this into the answer and I will accept it?

Comment: @altern Done. You might want to rewrite your `mapM_ (\x -> long lambda) objects` as `for_ objects $ \x -> long lambda` which is easier to indent, having the lambda in tail position. You'll need to import `Data.Foldable` if you choose to use `for_`.